# How do I utilize my Gcloud service account to run my script properly?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, scripting, service-accounts

Please forgive me if my post is sloppy, this is my first time on Stack Overflow.

I've written a Google API script to log the name, email, and IMAP status of all users on a domain. I created a service account with owner privileges in order to have permission to access the data. It appears that I didn't configure my service account credentials to work properly.

My error message is "ReferenceError: "OAuth2" is not defined."

This is the main code that I need to work. I can do this with just my owner email but I need to cycle through all the accounts on the domain.

When I try to cycle through all the accounts, I get "API call to gmail.users.settings.getImap failed with error: Delegation denied for name@example.com"

```
function listAllUsers() {
  var pageToken;
  var page;

  do {
    page = AdminDirectory.Users.list({
      domain: 'example.com',
      orderBy: 'givenName',
      maxResults: 100,
      pageToken: pageToken
    });
    var users = page.users;
    if (users) {
      for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        var user = users[i];
        Logger.log('%s (%s)', user.name.fullName, user.primaryEmail);

 var response =
    Gmail.Users.Settings.getImap (user.primaryEmail);
Logger.log('%s', response );

      }
    } else {
      Logger.log('No users found.');
    }
    pageToken = page.nextPageToken;
  } while (pageToken);
}
```

I have assumed that I need a service account to have permission to cycle through all of the users.
This is where I'm stuck trying to get the service account to work. My error message is:

"ReferenceError: "OAuth2" is not defined."

Am I even on the right track?

```
var JSON = {
    "private_key": "Your Private Key",
    "client_email": "serviceacount@example.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
    "client_id": "1234567890",
    "user_email": "name@example.com"
};

function getOAuthService(user) {
    return OAuth2.createService("Service Account")
        .setTokenUrl('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token')
        .setPrivateKey(JSON.private_key)
        .setIssuer(JSON.client_email)
        .setSubject(JSON.user_email)
        .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties())
        .setParam('access_type', 'offline')
        .setScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive');
}

function getUserFiles() {
    var service = getOAuthService();
    service.reset();
    if (service.hasAccess()) {
        var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?pageSize=1';
        var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
            headers: {
                Authorization: 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken()
            }
        });
        Logger.log(response.getContentText());
    }
}

function reset() {
    var service = getOAuthService();
    service.reset();
}
```

Comment: Did you connect the OAuth library to your script? Check out this repo to see how to do it https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-oauth2 This library isn't built-in, you have to explicitly add the lib to your script.

Comment: Thanks for responding! That was the fix for the OAuth error. I'm now getting the error "API call to gmail.users.settings.getImap failed with error: Delegation denied for user@example.com".

This was the original error I was getting and I thought that linking a service account would fix it. Would you be able to tell me what is causing this error? Is my service account still not linking properly to my code?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/guides/delegation